# Wifi hotspot transfer file

Tags: android

I am trying to send data in my app via wifi hotspot to all devices that are connected to that hotSpot. I searched a lot about this but I found nothing

Answer (score 0):

That's not how wifi hotspots work.  A wifi hotspot is just like connecting to a wifi router.  You can't broadcast to all connected clients.  Even if you could, there'd need to be an app on each device to listen for the incoming data to make it accept it.

Comment: OK. I meant that each device is listening for the incoming data and all the devices have that app to connect to that hotspot